# Webstorm & Partial Views

Tags: webstorm

In Webstorm is there any support for "partial" views?

For example, I have a chunk of html that will be injected (via angular.js) into the main page. If I'm working on that chunk and I create a new CSS tag, the "Create Selector" will not list any css files since they are not referenced in the partial, but rather in the "parent" view.

From what I can tell it only looks for CSS files that are referenced in the head tag. Normally this makes perfect sense; don't create new CSS properties in a file that won't be available. But in the case of partial views, they will be injected into a page that has several CSS files linked to it. Is there any way to inform Webstorm that these are partial views and that the CSS files will be available at runtime? In other words, these partial views are children of a parent view, and I'd like Webstorm to be aware of this hierarchy.

Comment: There is no such support AFAIK. RE CSS: if no specific CSS files are referenced in this file (via `link` or `style` tags) then styles from ALL files will be offered for completion. But when creating not-existing-yet selector, it will not know where to create it indeed. I guess filling Feature Request tickets on Issue Tracker is the way to go here (but check for existing tickets before submitting yours): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB